# Slick2d Can't find image even though it's in the right area

Tags: java, image, slick2d

I'm following the tutorials found on the Slick2D website, and upon loading Images to my program, I get an error that says:

```
Tue Nov 01 14:12:47 EDT 2011 INFO:Slick Build #274
Tue Nov 01 14:12:47 EDT 2011 INFO:LWJGL Version: 2.8.1
Tue Nov 01 14:12:47 EDT 2011 INFO:OriginalDisplayMode: 1024 x 768 x 32 @60Hz
Tue Nov 01 14:12:47 EDT 2011 INFO:TargetDisplayMode: 800 x 600 x 0 @0Hz
Tue Nov 01 14:12:48 EDT 2011 INFO:Starting display 800x600
Tue Nov 01 14:12:48 EDT 2011 INFO:Use Java PNG Loader = true
Tue Nov 01 14:12:48 EDT 2011 INFO:Controllers not available
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource not found: C:\Users\Andrew\workspace\SirSlime\data\images\lang.jpg
   at org.newdawn.slick.util.ResourceLoader.getResourceAsStream(ResourceLoader.java:69)
   at org.newdawn.slick.opengl.InternalTextureLoader.getTexture(InternalTextureLoader.java:169)
   at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:196)
   at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:170)
   at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:158)
   at org.newdawn.slick.Image.<init>(Image.java:136)
   at awesome.Main.init(Main.java:33)
   at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:390)
   at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:314)
   at awesome.Main.main(Main.java:19)
```

The line:

> Resource not found: C:\Users\Andrew\workspace\SirSlime\data\images\lang.jpg\

confuses me as the picture I'm trying to load IS in that exact area. This is the code I'm using to load:

```
 // ship = new Image("../../data/images/ship.png"); Does not work
  // land = new Image("../../data/images/land.jpg"); Does not work
  ship = new Image("C:\\Users\\Andrew\\workspace\\SirSlime\\data\\images\\ship.png");
  land = new Image("C:\\Users\\Andrew\\workspace\\SirSlime\\data\\images\\lang.jpg");
```

Comment: The `ship.png` image that comes first loads okay?

Comment: I know this sounds redundant, but can you do a `dir` in your images folder, and post the results? I do remember dealing with a JPG issue some time ago if the JPG was saved as "JPG 2000" format, as opposed to plain old JPG. Check your image, and explicitly save it in the plain format and see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for being obvious, but in one place you use the file name "lang.jpg" and in another "land.jpg", just a typo?